# How can I set a variable width in my CSS or Tailwind class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am getting the width from my Django View, but I do not know if I can make it variable in CSS.

I’ve been trying to set the Tailwind, but I imagine that it is not the right thing to do:

```html
{% for movie in movies %}
<div id="bar" class="w-[{movie.score}]"
style="transition: 1s">
          {{movie.score}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I am also trying to do it directly in CSS, but the style does not accept a variable as:

```html
{% for movie in movies %}
<div id="bar" style="transition: 1s; width: {{movie.score}}; ">
          {{movie.score}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I’ve also tried to change it using JavaScript, but I have to select multiple elements because there will be various bars. So, this just not worked. I receive messages that the movies were declared before if I use let, but using var nothing changes.

```py
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(MoviesRatePage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['movies'] = movies

        return context
```

```
{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var movies = "{{movies}}";

      for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
        document.querySelectorAll("#bar")[i].style.width = `${movies[i].score}%`;
      }

    </script>
    {% endblock javascript %}
```

Thus, I want to make the bar width the same as the movie’s score.

Comment: declare a variable in your general (global) css root. Change it's value from django, javascript,.... whatever... just the value, not the declaration

Answer (score 0):

The second solution - with setting width directly via `style` attribute should technically work. The only missing thing is unit for width. Append `px` and it should be fine:

```
{% for movie in movies %}
<div id="bar" style="transition: 1s; width: {{movie.score}}px; ">
          {{movie.score}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```